# Cocos2d-x Buttons - MenuItemSprite Vs Button

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.x

Cocos2d-x Version 3.17

// Create Button : Type - 1

```
{
    Sprite *spr1 = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName(FRAME_MM_PLAY);
    Sprite *spr2 = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName(FRAME_MM_PLAY);

    spr2->setColor( Color3B(200, 200, 200) );

    auto *playButton = MenuItemSprite::create(spr1, spr2, CC_CALLBACK_1(CBirdMainMenu::playBtnPress, this));
    playButton->setScale(1.0f);
    playButton->setEnabled(true);

    auto playMenu = Menu::create(playButton, nullptr);
}
```

// Create Button : Type - 2

```
Button *infoButton
    {
        infoButton = Button::create(FRAME_MM_INFO,FRAME_MM_INFO,FRAME_MM_INFO,Widget::TextureResType::PLIST);
        infoButton->setZoomScale(0.2f);
        infoButton->setPressedActionEnabled(true);
        infoButton->addTouchEventListener([&](Ref* sender, cocos2d::ui::Widget::TouchEventType type){
            switch (type)
            {
                case ui::Widget::TouchEventType::BEGAN:
                    break;
                case ui::Widget::TouchEventType::ENDED:
                    this->infoButtonPress();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });

        This->addChild(infoButton, 2);
    }
```

In Type-2 how to change color of button when clicked. I used single image for all states. I don't like to use separate image. Is it possible to change color of selected sprite in Type2 ? In Type1, for MenuItemSprite , we can easily set color for selected image……In Type-2, if I call setColor on Button, then it is crashing.

```
infoButton->setColor(Color3B(200, 200, 200)); //Crashed on this
```

Don't know how to change color of button when pressed.

Comment: i don't see any problem with this. assuming that FRAME_MM_X is a char array of the image names and the image is stored in a texture atlas since you are using `Widget::TextureResType::PLIST`. What is the crash btw?

Comment: @Yucel_K crash happens only when we call infoButton->setColor...otherwise no crash.

Comment: have you tried changing the colour right after initializing the Button? in my cocos2dx, everything works fine. im suspecting maybe`infoButton` pointer becomes invalid before `setColor`  is called. what is the crash you get?

Comment: @Yucel_K here is screenshots..thanks for looking. https://app.box.com/s/hefysv8c8nccpcz41piv0z5e6fkceiwc

Comment: can you show me the where you intializing `toolbar`  pointer?I believe i know where its gets released  but want to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are creating the button and assigning to the `InfoButton` pointer.

```
infoButton = Button::create(FRAME_MM_INFO,FRAME_MM_INFO,FRAME_MM_INFO,Widget::TextureResType::PLIST);
```

the problem is though your `infoButton` is a local pointer.

```
Button *infoButton;
  {
    ...
    ...
```

from the screenshot you have provided, I can see that it's locally created in `CBirdMenu::SetupMenu()`.

you then add the `info button` as a child to an object pointed by a pointer called `toolBar` However the moment the  `CBirdMenu::SetupMenu()` ends, your `infoButton` will no longer be recognised by the lambda expression.

one way and perhaps easiest way is to fix your problem is using dynamic casting on the lambda parameter `Ref* sender` within the lambda expression.

```
InfoButton->addTouchEventListener([&](Ref* sender, cocos2d::ui::Widget::TouchEventType type)
{
    cocos2d::ui::Button * infButton = dynamic_cast<cocos2d::ui::Button*>(sender);
    if(infButton)//check if casting done properly
       infButton->setColor(Color3B(0, 200, 0)); //colour set to green.
});
```

or alternativly,  instead of having a local pointer `infoButton`, store it as a class member of `CBirdMenu`. this way `infoButton` will never get lost while the `cBirdMenu` exists.

here is a quick demo.
the header file;

```
    #include "cocos2d.h"
    #include "ui\CocosGUI.h"
    class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::Layer
    {
    public:
        static cocos2d::Scene* createScene();
        virtual bool init();
        void menuCloseCallback(cocos2d::Ref* pSender);
        CREATE_FUNC(HelloWorld);
    private:
        cocos2d::ui::Button * InfoButton; //member of HelloWorld.
    };
```

notice the private member `cocos2d::ui::Button * InfoButton;`
And finally the source file where the button is instantiated and assigned to the `infoButton` pointer.

```
// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
    //////////////////////////////
    // 1. super init first
    if ( !Layer::init() )
        return false;

    Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();

    InfoButton = cocos2d::ui::Button::create("HelloWorld.png", "HelloWorld.png", "HelloWorld.png", ui::Widget::TextureResType::LOCAL);
    InfoButton->setColor(Color3B(255, 0, 0)); //colour is set to red as suppose to.
    InfoButton->setTitleFontSize(InfoButton->getTitleFontSize() * 0.7);
    InfoButton->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width / 2 + origin.x, visibleSize.height / 2 + origin.y));
    InfoButton->addTouchEventListener([&](Ref* sender, cocos2d::ui::Widget::TouchEventType type)
    {
        InfoButton->setColor(Color3B(0, 200, 0)); //colour set to green.
    });
    // add the button as a child to this layer
    this->addChild(InfoButton, 2);
    return true;
}
```

if you apply the same principle to your code, this should solve your current problem with the `lambda`. However I'm still not sure what your`toolBar` class does since this is not included in the code. if `toolBar` is a custom class, i recommend you to move your `infoButton` from `CBirdMenu` to `toolBar` instead if you going with the second approach to adress your issue.

Comment: Thanks a lots for your answer...both solution worked.